# What's the correct way of having two different plugins for one method?

Tags: magento2, plugin, after-plugin

I have this `afterGetList` plugin in

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderCompanyAccount.php

```
public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        $orders
    )
    {
        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
        //do stuff
        }
        return $orders;
    }
```

And in Vendor\Module\etc\webapi_rest\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_repository" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderCompanyAccount"
                disabled="false"
                sortOrder="200"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

---

I want to add another `afterGetList` plugin.

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderComment.php

```
public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        $orders
    )
    {
        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
        //do other stuff
        }
        return $orders;
    }
```

And this time in Vendor\Module\etc\webapi_rest\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderComment">
        <plugin name="order_repository" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderComment"
                disabled="false"
                sortOrder="210"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

If I enable one of these modules, they are working fine. **However**, if I enable both, **none** of them are working anymore. I tried with `sortOrder` but it has no effect.

So, my question is: **How to have more than one afterGetList plugin enabled at the same time?**
Or better asked: **What's the correct way of having two different plugins for one method at all?**

Comment: Why do you want two plugin for same method ?

Comment: One#s doing one thing, the other is doing something else. I thought it would be better to have two plugins instead of writing both into one. I that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, but **you added the same plugin name on both instances** `plugin name="order_repository"` and according to the doc, we have:

> `<plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />`
>  -> **plugin name** - an arbitrary plugin name that
> identifies a plugin. Also used to merge the configurations for the
> plugin.

So basically if you enable both your plugins, then the configuration will be merged based on the plugin name which is used as identifier and only one of them will work.

Just add a unique identifier for each of your plugins and try again.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, that's it. Sometimes, mistakes are so stupid. It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: no poblem :D sometimes fresh eyes do the trick :D